# Have sendmail rewrite incoming domain to be something elsewhere

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail

I have a local network with lots of devices that use email addresses in the domain of foo.local When it sends email to my psfc.mit.edu email server, I want all the email address in that local domain, transformed into @psfc.mit.edu. Otherwise, I get this email address, and it gets rejected.  Any suggestions? Thanks.

ctladdr=ro...@www.foo.local (0/0), delay=00:01:21, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=cyrusv2, pri=210524, relay=localhost, dsn=4.4.2, stat=Deferred: Name server: localhost: host name lookup failure